# Unable to update data using prisma

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using prisma to update some fields but i am getting error.
I am using unique id to update the data.
Before update i am able to get all the data from table so prisma is working on select

```
        const cartUpdate = await prisma.custom_checkout__c.update({
            where: {

                id: uniqueId,
            },
            data: {
                status__c: 'Checkout completed',
                coupon_code__c: coupon,
                checkout_id__c: result.subscription.id,
            }
        })
```

Error is below

```
PrismaClientUnknownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.custom_checkout__c.update()` invocation:


    Error occurred during query execution:
    ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error { kind: Db, cause: Some(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E42883), message: "function get_xmlbinary() does not exist", detail: None, hint: Some("No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."), position: Some(Internal { position: 2, query: "(get_xmlbinary() = 'base64')" }), where_: Some("PL/pgSQL function hc_custom_checkout__c_status() line 3 at IF"), schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("parse_func.c"), line: Some(629), routine: Some("ParseFuncOrColumn") }) }) })
        at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (/Users/bi
```

Comment: Can you share your schema file? Have you referenced any database function: get_xmlbinary in the schema?

Comment: There are no references to this function. Schema is simple models generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "darwin-arm64", "linux-musl", "linux-arm64-openssl-1.1.x"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URI")
}

Comment: Is it happening on latest version of Prisma?

Comment: yes i am using latest version

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproduction? Or just a link to GitHub repository if it is open source.